# Confusion matrix for RCNN Detector in Matlab

Tags: matlab

```
I tagged 300 images using the alexnet neural network I completed the training of the rcnn detector object. I can test the pictures one by one, containing 12 different people, 100 of which are not labeled.    
    testImage = imread('E:.....\....jpg');
    [bboxes, score, label] = detect(detector, testImage, 'MiniBatchSize', 128)
    T = 0.7; 
    idx = score >= T;
    s = score(idx);
    lbl = label(idx);
    bbox = bboxes(idx, :); 
    outputImage = testImage;
    for ii = 1 : size(bbox, 1)
        annotation = sprintf('%s: (Confidence = %f)', lbl(ii), s(ii));   
        outputImage = insertObjectAnnotation(outputImage, 'rectangle', bbox(ii,:), annotation); 
    end
    figure
    imshow(outputImage)

But for 100 test pictures, each with 12 people (12 labels), I cannot plot confusion matrix that gives the success of the network, the correct number of predictions. There are many examples, which one should I use? For example, in an experiment I get an error like this.

Example

net = trainNetwork(XTrain,YTrain,layers,options);

[XTest,YTest] = trainingData;
YPredicted = classify(net,XTest);
plotconfusion(YTest,YPredicted)

Eror
[XTest,YTest] = detector;
```

Insufficient number of outputs from right hand side of equal sign to satisfy assignment.

I have 100 test pictures. There is a rcnn detector trained using Alexnet. How can I see the correct number of tagging of 12 people (12 labels) in 100 images with the confusion matrix? How can I create the success of the RCNN detector for 100 images and 12 different labels?

Comment: You might look into [classification performance evaluation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classification-model-building-and-assessment.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav). MATLAB's documentation is pretty good, you should try looking there before posting.

Comment: I am trying to find the correct tagging rate of the people in the picture with face recognition. When I test the pictures one by one, some people cannot tag them at all. When I try confusion for rcnn detector and test pictures, I get a type mismatch error. 
Thank you for your interest.

Comment: If you're getting an error, then why haven't you posted it? Please add the error code along with a [mre] to your question.

Comment: sorry my question had to be clearer [c,cm,ind,per] = confusion(targets,outputImage)
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in confusion (line 42)
if any(size(targets)~=size(outputs))

Comment: Please add all updates and clarifications to the question itself using [edit]. You'll also need to tell us *at least* the dimensions of `targets` and `outputImage`.